Theoretical vs. actual – How absolute are speed limits in Canada?
My Canadian friends say that the speed limits in Canada are more like suggestions and that no one drives within the speed limit. In fact, they say that driving at the speed limit while all the other drivers are going faster could cause a hazard. Therefore, they say I should drive above the speed limit in such scenarios.
Is it legal for me to drive somewhat above the speed limit, such as to match the flow of traffic? In case the province matters, we’ll use British Colombia.

Louisiana: https://louisianaspeedingticket.com/how-much-over-the-speeding-limit-is-considered-speeding-and-debunking-the-10-mph-myth/

I think you should explicitly specify if you mean "Is there a speed threshold above the posted limit but below a numerical threshold where practically one will not get a speed ticket", "Can one practically get a speed ticket if one matches the flow of traffic" and "According to the letter of the law if there a threshold above the posted limit where one cannot get a ticket".

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Depends on police discretion
australia
Speed limits are legally absolute, but police and traffic departments (who operate the fixed and mobile cameras) have discretion.
Officially, there is no tolerance for speeding but the statistics and anecdote show that it happens. For example, fines for up to 10km/h over are rare in New South Wales except for school zones and it is not uncommon for police to shave a few km/h off the ticket to drop the driver into a lower penalty. Conversely, there are plenty of fines in Victoria for as little as 2km/h.
In addition, in NSW there is an official leniency policy for people with a 10 year plus clean driving record that downgrades one fine + points to a caution, subject to the seriousness of the offence. That’s after the police have decided to book you.

uk

Is it legal for me to drive somewhat above the speed limit, such as to match the flow of traffic?

There are two literal and two practical questions here:

Is it legal for me to drive somewhat above the speed limit?
Does the flow of traffic affect that, such that it could be legal to exceed the speed limit if I judged that safer?
Is there any chance of getting a ticket if I drive somewhat above the speed limit?
Does the flow of traffic affect that, such that one may not get a ticket if one is only keeping up with the traffic?

1 and 3 are covered in a 2017 police document that may no longer be totally accurate but gives an idea:

9.2 Driving at any speed over the limit is an offence and the police are not restricted and may prosecute.



Does the flow of traffic affect that, such that it could be legal to exceed the speed limit if one judged that safer?

I have no good references, but I am fairly certain there is no such exception in law.

Does the flow of traffic affect that, such that one may not get a ticket if one is only keeping up with the traffic?

While there may be some situations where a police officer will not charge a row of traffic where they may prosecute a single car, the vast majority of speed enforcement is by camera.  These do not determine if you are in traffic.  I have personally witnessed, while travelling the other way, the traffic cameras of a variable speed limit motorway constantly flashing on all three lanes.  I suspect that was generating tickets at approximately 3/second.
